# Vorticity transport 2D using Lax-Wendroff 2 steps scheme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, transport-equation

I have to solve a 2D vorticity transport equation (very similar to viscous Burgers 2D). I had to change the equation for a non-dimensional form.

**Vorticity transport Eq.**:

$$\zeta_t+u \cdot \zeta_x + v \cdot \zeta_y=\frac{1}{\text{Re}}(\zeta_{xx}+\zeta_{yy})$$

I have to use the Lax-Wendroff 2 steps scheme. I've made a discretization:

**Lax-Wendroff 2 Steps:**

**1º STEP:**
$$\zeta^{n+1/2}_{i,j} = S^n_{12} - 2\Omega(u_{i,j}\Delta I^n_{i+1/2,j} + v_{i,j}\Delta J^n_{i,j+1/2}) + \Theta(S^n_{
32} - S^n_{12})$$
**2º STEP:**
$$\zeta^{n+1}_{i,j} = \zeta^{n}_{i,j} - \Omega(u_{i,j}\Delta I^{n+1/2}_{i+1/2,j} + v_{i,j}\Delta J^{n+1/2}_{i,j+1/2}) + \Theta(S^n - 4\zeta^{n}_{i,j})$$
where,
$$S^n_{12} = \zeta^n_{i+1/2,j} + \zeta^n_{i-1/2,j} + \zeta^n_{i,j+1/2} + \zeta^n_{i,j-1/2}$$
$$S^n_{32} = \zeta^n_{i+3/2,j} + \zeta^n_{i-3/2,j} + \zeta^n_{i,j+3/2} + \zeta^n_{i,j-3/2}$$
$$\Delta J^n_{i+1/2,j} = \zeta^n_{i+1/2,j} - \zeta^n_{i-1/2,j}$$
$$\Delta J^n_{i+3/2,j} = \zeta^n_{i,j+1/2} - \zeta^n_{i,j-1/2}$$
$$\Omega = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} $$
$$\Theta = \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2\,\text{Re}} $$

First question: I'm not sure if this discretization is correct. Second problem: I don't know how to analyze the stability condition. Can I use the same stability condition for a Lax-Wendroff 1-step scheme?

Results: **VORTICITY**
[image]

Comment: It's the convection-diffusion equation, isn't it?

Comment: Yes! The term with $\zeta_x$ is the convection, and $\zeta_{xx}$ is the diffusion term.

Comment: That's the first time I see this equation being called 'Viscous two-dimensional Burger's equation'. I'm not well acquainted with the Lax-Wendroff method, but your discretization seems to be alright. You will probably find the stability criteria in specialized literature, such as Fletcher's Computational Methods for Fluid Dynamics. However, I think it's much more common to solve this equation numerically with the FTCS scheme, and I have been solving this very equation using FTCS; if you consider the FTCS, you can find the stability criteria [here](https://doi.org/10.1002/fld.1650040905).

Comment: @rafa11111 The name is *vorticity transport equation non-dimensional*, but it's very similar with *viscous burger's equation*. I've already solved this problem using the FTCS scheme, but i have to solve it with LW 2 Steps scheme too.

Comment: Unless $u$ and $v$ defined previously, you'll need some more equations.

Comment: @Mattos I do have an initial values for $u$ and $v$